# Is "Version" a Reserved word in TRANSACT-SQL? (Shows Blue but not in Reserved word list)

Tags: sql, sql-server, reserved-words

I was writing a `Stored Procedure` today and Wrote the line:

```
SELECT pv1.Version FROM depl...
```

and the word `Version` turned blue shown below:

[image]

so I assumed it was a reserved word, so did some investigating here:

[Reserved Keywords (TRANSACT-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx)

But could not find the word `Version` in the list.

Is `Version` a SQL reserved word, and if not why is my word `Version` displaying blue? I am using SQL Management Studio 2012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you rightly noted, `Version` is not in the official reserved word list. It's just a "feature" of SQL Server Management Studio that is showing it in blue.

There are many words like this. Here's a few more:

```
DESCRIPTION
SERVER
INSTEAD
```

There are even some words that show as pink such as `LOOKUP`.

Comment: It's because the syntax highlighter isn't context aware. Because `VERSION` (and the other words you've highlighted) has a specific meaning in one particular context, they highlight it, even though in most contexts it's not relevant

Comment: @DavidG thank you for the information is there a list of these words somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

"Version" is not a SQL Server reserved keyword.

However, it is used in a global variable used to show the OS name & version, SQL Server version, SQL Server patches and hardware attributes of the SQL Server being used.

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```

Perhaps the "Version" text turns blue in Transact-SQL because it is known to SQL Server in the context of this global variable. I'm not sure about that, this is just a theory.

Comment: Yes, I also suspect "version" is blue because of @@VERSION. Note in the docs it's described as a function. "global variables" really are functions, with an arcane syntax to call them.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer - no, it isn't. Here's an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1d89f) that uses it as a column name in SQL-Server 2014 to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can always if in doubt wrap your column name in brackets to use reserved words as column names:

`select p1.[Version] from dpl...`