# Is CARD a keyword in SQL? or: List of all SQL keywords

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I'm adding a table to my database - `CREATE TABLE dbo.Card` - and SSMS is highlighting the word `Card`. I'm searching the internet trying to find out what that word means to SQL and if it is a keyword or not. I don't see it anywhere on Microsoft's list of [SQL Reserved Words](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

The main reason I care, aside from the highlighting bothering me, is that I want to avoid using any reserved words or keywords as schema/table/column/etc... names. When I absolutely have to - existing databases - I like to use square brackets to make things explicit.

**Is `Card` a reserved word or keyword in SQL, or for any other reason unsafe to use as an identifier?**

**If it is safe to use, can anyone explain why SSMS is highlighting it?**

If it is not 100% safe to use as a table name I'll most likely choose a different name.

```
Windows 8.1
SSMS v17.7
Red Gate - Up to date, including SQL Prompt 9.4.9
SQL Server 2017 (14.0)
Database Compatibility Level 2017 (140)
```

***UPDATE***

It looks like the main consensus is:

1. It is not a reserved or keyword
2. SSMS highlights it because reasons... It's probably used somewhere by MS SQL Server or SSMS

At this point I'm just terribly curious, but at least I know there's no need to worry. Thanks everyone for your answers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30805490/is-version-a-reserved-word-in-transact-sql-shows-blue-but-not-in-reserved-wo

Comment: Thanks for the link @AaronDietz. Very similar question, though I'm wondering why specifically this word is highlighted. The best guess I can make is some relation to cardinality but I really don't know

Comment: I found [this question on dba.StackExchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/148752/sql-server-management-studio-highlights-a-word-that-does-not-appear-to-be-a-rese) which sort of answers the question, but I couldn't find any context where "card" would fit into the case noted there.

Comment: Well, for reference, `start_date` is highlighted as blue because it's used in a create certificate command.  You may have to dig through every command in SQL Server to find an exact reason.

Comment: i cannot answer WHY, but how to avoid highlight: take table name into [] `CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CARD]`

Comment: Just a wild guess. But I noticed on the [List of future Keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?#future-keywords) that `CARDINALITY` is in there. Maybe SSMS already highlights the abbrev `CARD` for that, just in case?

Comment: Seems like CARD is such an ambiguous table name that it is likely not a great choice anyway. ;)

Answer (score 1):

No, `card` is not a reversed word in Microsoft SQLServer or SQL ANSI standard.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I updated my question to make it slightly more clear that I would also like to know why SSMS is highlighting it.

Answer (score 0):

**Card** is definitely not a reserved keyword in SQL Server

You can check the complete list of reserved words [Reserved Keywords (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms189822(v=sql.90))

> SSMS highlights it because reasons... It's probably used somewhere by
>   MS SQL Server or SSMS

They are various keywords that have been subjectively chosen by Microsoft and placed into a list within the query editor syntax coloring file.

I suggest it's always good to use **Delimited Identifiers** (`[]` or ") when specifying table name and column names.

For example, the script you are using should be written as

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Card](<Columns>)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I mentioned in my question, I have already checked Microsoft's Reserved Keywords list, and I do typically use square brackets for reserved words. At this point I'm really just wondering why Microsoft chose to highlight that word.

Comment: @Hill, as I have mentioned in the answer SSMS uses color syntax highlighting for keywords that are not necessarily reserved keywords, for example start_date. There are words which are configured for the IDE.